# Stuck at successive differentiation problem, suspecting error in question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is my very first submission so I wish **Hi!** to everyone. This is indeed a homework problem that involves using Leibniz's formula for n-th derivative. Although this is uncharted territory to me, I have been able to solve few other simpler problems, but not this. Maybe I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Here's the question: If $y = (\sin^{-1}x)^2,$ prove that $(1-x^2).y_2 - xy_1 = 2$ and hence prove that $(1-x^2).y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}-n^2y_n=0$.

To avoid large write up, I am just mentioning that I have been available to prove the first part. The problem starts from the *second* part which I hope you all would be kind enough to check for any errors. This exact calculation has been attempted quite a lot of times only to get stuck at the ending.

\begin{align}
   2 & =(1-x^2).y_2 - xy_1 &&\text{Already proven} \\
   0 & = (1-x^2).y_{n+2}+^nC_1.y_{n+1}(-2x)+^nC_2(-2).y_n - (x.y_{n+1}+^nC_1.y_n)&&\text{Leibniz's formula,} \\
 & = (1-x^2).y_{n+2} -2nxy_{n+1} -2n(n-1)y_n-x.y_{n+1}-n.y_n \\
& = (1 - x^2).y_{n+2} - (2n+1)xy_{n+1} - (2n^2-2n+n).y_n\\
& = (1 - x^2).y_{n+2} - (2n+1)xy_{n+1} - (2n^2-n).y_n &&\text{Stuck here}\\
\end{align}

I hope anyone will be able to enlighten me on this. Cheers!

Comment: Who are all the $y_n$? You don't define them.

Comment: @alex Thank you for your tip to improve clarification. I will surely add it to my post. To answer your question, $y_n = \frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake after the next line you use Leibniz's formula.

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 2 \end{array} \right)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

and congratulations.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing my mistake. I was very sure I was doing something that didnt catch my eye and probably _careless_! Using your hint helped me reach to the sdcond expression to be proved. I will accept your answer following the StackExchange rules.